# When is $R[x]$ a Euclidean domain?

Tags: ring-theory, euclidean-domain

It is well-known that $R[x]$ is a PID iff $R$ is a field. Is there a necessary **and** sufficient condition on $R$ for $R[x]$ to be a Euclidean domain?

Comment: The condition is the same, namely that $R$ be a field. As is well known, if $R$ is a field, then $R[X]$ is a Euclidean domain. On the other hand, if $R[X]$ is a Euclidean domain, then it's a PID, and so $R$ is a field.

Comment: Oh I see. So in other words, $R[X]$ cannot be a non-Euclidean PID?

Comment: Yep! (characters)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question! If $R$ is a field, then $R[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. Conversely, if $R[x]$ is a Euclidian domain, then $R[x]$ is a PID, so $R$ is a field.

Comment: Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: Cheers :) nice to e-see you